# Alternative icons for Mathematica v11 and v12

Tags: customization

Is there a simple possibility to use gif/jpg images of polyhedron spikeys as icons for Mathematica versions 11 and 12 instead of the "2D" polygonal icon provided by Mathematica v11 and v12 ? The existing icons are not very attractive.

Comment: "icon" as in icon for e.g. the desktop?

Comment: I do have the Mathematica 10 spikey icon for macOS if you'd like. You can set it to be the icon following Bill's answer below. If you have Windows or Linux, I'm not totally sure if the macOS icon can be turned into an icon for those systems, or if you'd need to get the icon from someone else.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac you can change the icon for Mathematica the same way you change any icon. Select the application, and choose get info (command I). This opens up a window that has the icon in the upper left hand corner. Now go to a folder (or file) with the icon you want to use and choose get info. Copy the icon you want and paste onto the icon you want to change. You will need to restart Mathematica before the new icon shows up.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use an application like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to modify resources within Windows executables. After loading the .exe you can change the icon with *Actions* -> *Replace Icon …*. You'll probably want to create a copy before trying anything like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not sure whether the application "Resource Hacker" will help. I have already extracted from a Mathematica notebook "Spikey.nb" two (downsized polyhedral) images for V11 and V12. I suppose that these png- or jpg images must be converted into icons which are placed in a new dll file or in another already existing one such as SHELL32.dll etc.